# Assign int array to in pointer in struct

Tags: c

I have created below C struct.

```
typedef struct KnightsMartSale {
char firstName[21];
char lastName[21];
int numItemsOnList;
int *itemsPurchased; // array of item numbers
struct KnightsMartSale *next;
} KMSale;
```

Here is it possible to assign int array to the **int *itemsPurchased** pointer?
If it is possible how print the values?

Comment: The thing you want is called _flexible array member_.

Comment: And that needs to be the last member in the structure.

Comment: Or it could just be a pointer to a `malloc`ed array.

Comment: Anyone show me an example. I'm new to C language.

Comment: Google. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: Does he want flexible arrays in the middle of a linked list? Or just asking for itemsPurchased = malloc(sizeof(int) * n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd allocate memory according to the size of the array you want to copy into `itemsPurchased` and also "remember" the number of possible items in `numItemsOnList`.

So suppose you have a given array of ints, let's say `myArray`, then the code for copying and printing could look as follows:

```
typedef struct KnightsMartSale {
    char firstName[21];
    char lastName[21];
    int numItemsOnList;
    int *itemsPurchased; // array of item numbers
    struct KnightsMartSale *next;
} KMSale;

int main() {

    KMSale kmsale;

    int myArray[] = { 20,30,40,50 };

    kmsale.numItemsOnList = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]);
    kmsale.itemsPurchased = calloc(kmsale.numItemsOnList,sizeof(int));
    memcpy(kmsale.itemsPurchased,myArray,kmsale.numItemsOnList*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<kmsale.numItemsOnList; i++) {
        printf("item #%d: %d\n",i,kmsale.itemsPurchased[i]);
    }


    // kmsale not needed any more, free memory:
    free(kmsale.itemsPurchased);
}
```

Output:

```
item #0: 20
item #1: 30
item #2: 40
item #3: 50
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you use calloc followed by memcpy? malloc would achieve the same thing, but faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just some rapid prototype coding... Perhaps it might direct you into the right way...

```
KMSale foo; // sample struct on stack, not initialized!
int my_buffer[12]; // not initialized stack buffer!

/* Assign pointer */
foo.itemsPurchased = my_buffer; // point to my_buffer

/* Print the first element via the struct... */
printf("%02x", foo.itemsPurchased[0]);
```

Comment: Why on earth was my answer down voted? Because I did not solve the homework entirely, otherwise tell me whats wrong in the code!? The "right" solution proposes a dynamic memory allocation on a super small buffer, the for loop counter variable is out of scope, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is it possible to assign int array to the int *itemsPurchased pointer? If it is possible how print the values?

Yes we can assign an array to a pointer as array is a constant pointer and reverse is invalid.

But this assignment should be used very carefully as array will be a stack variable and scope of the variable should be taken care before accessing this structure pointer

Also this method can be preferred over the dynamic memory allocation where memory fragmentation is a concern by malloc and free and we can avoid the dynamic allocation overhead.

Following is the code for this and output of print value in the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct KnightsMartSale {
    char firstName[21];
    char lastName[21];
    int numItemsOnList;
    int *itemsPurchased; // array of item numbers
    struct KnightsMartSale *next;
} KMSale;

int main() {

    KMSale sale;
    int iPos = 0;

    int Array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    sale.numItemsOnList = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0]);
    sale.itemsPurchased = Array;

    for (iPos=0; iPos < sale.numItemsOnList; iPos++) {
        printf("sale %d: %d\n", iPos, sale.itemsPurchased[iPos]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sale 0: 1
sale 1: 2
sale 2: 3
sale 3: 4
sale 4: 5
```